# How to group a two dimensional list in python based on an attribute?

Tags: python, list, grouping

Example:
Here is my 2D list:

```
a=[]
a.append(['abc.com','ars','league1','man'])
a.append(['abcxyz.com','hah','league2','bah'])
a.append(['abcd.com','gah','league3','fah'])
a.append(['abcm.com','ada','league1','ads'])
a.append(['abcxyzf.com','gha','league1','tra'])
a.append(['abcdg.com','jhi','league2','yui'])
```

What I want my output to be is:

```
print(a)
Output:
['abc.com','ars','league1','man']
['abcm.com','ada','league1','ads']
['abcxyzf.com','gha','league1','tra']
['abcxyz.com','hah','league2','bah']
['abcdg.com','jhi','league2','yui']
['abcd.com','gah','league3','fah']
```

That is I want to group my list depending on the attribute at index 2.

At least, I want the distinct values of column 3.

Comment: What's there to group when you have only one row? Please provide an actual [mcve] and demonstrate what you want to achieve, please.

Comment: Your question is confusing. 1) There are no tuples here. 2) What's the point of the nested list if it only contains a single list? Is this just a toy example, and in reality there are more sub-lists? 3) What should the result look like? Should it be a dict? Should it be a list? Please post an example of input data and the grouped result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to sort the list with the item at second index as the key.

```
a=[]
a.append(['abc.com','ars','league1','man'])
a.append(['abcxyz.com','hah','league2','bah'])
a.append(['abcd.com','gah','league3','fah'])
a.append(['abcm.com','ada','league1','ads'])
a.append(['abcxyzf.com','gha','league1','tra'])
a.append(['abcdg.com','jhi','league2','yui'])

a.sort(key=lambda k: k[2])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[['abc.com', 'ars', 'league1', 'man'],
 ['abcm.com', 'ada', 'league1', 'ads'],
 ['abcxyzf.com', 'gha', 'league1', 'tra'],
 ['abcxyz.com', 'hah', 'league2', 'bah'],
 ['abcdg.com', 'jhi', 'league2', 'yui'],
 ['abcd.com', 'gah', 'league3', 'fah']]
```

Comment: +1. This is the best solution if the only requirement is to sort the list. If you also need a list of distinct leagues, I recommend the dictionary-based method where this comes for free.

Answer (score 2):

Your terminology is confusing: what you have in `a` is a *list of lists* rather than a *list of tuples*. However, this is *not* relevant in the solution provided below.

In addition, note that attributes are not involved here. We access *list elements*.

The classic Python way, which deals with both your questions (grouping and unique keys), is to use `collections.defaultdict`:

**Setup**

```
a = []
a.append(['data1','data2','data3','data4'])
a.append(['data21','data22','data3','data24'])
a.append(['data31','data32','data4','data34'])
```

**Solution**

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in a:
    d[item[2]].append(item)
```

**Result**

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'data3': [['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'],
                       ['data21', 'data22', 'data3', 'data24']],
             'data4': [['data31', 'data32', 'data4', 'data34']]})
```

**Explanation**

- Initialise a default dictionary of lists.
- Iterate your list of lists.
- Append items to keys determined by the 3rd element.

---

Your sorted list format is then possible via `sorted`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

sorter = map(itemgetter(1), sorted(d.items()))
res = list(chain.from_iterable(sorter)))

[['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'],
 ['data21', 'data22', 'data3', 'data24'],
 ['data31', 'data32', 'data4', 'data34']]
```

`sorter` sorts items of the dictionary as if they were key-value tuples (so, since keys are unique, by key). `itemgetter(1)` extracts the second element of the result, i.e. the values.

`chain.from_iterable` is used to flatten nested lists in an efficient way.